# Why is my plugin not hooking into events?

Tags: development, plugin, plugin-events

I have a plugin that looks like this:

```
class plgExtensionLogInstall extends JPlugin
{

    function onExtensionAfterInstall($installer, $extensionId) 
    {
        JLog::add("Extension installed: ".$extensionId, JLog::DEBUG, 'plg_extension_log_install);
    }
}
```

This installs correctly and I can enable it, but when I install another extension it is never triggered.

Putting some extra logging in `/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php` I can see two event listeners hooked to `onextensionafterinstall` but neither of them is mine. The Extension XML file only contains the standard extension description and a files section like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="extension">
    <name>Plugin Logger</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="installer_log">installer_log.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

The event is never triggered, but if the code is broken it does crash when the installer would run. What is missing from my class or configuration?

Comment: Only difference I really see between your plugin and one of the core plugins shipped in Joomla (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/plugins/extension/joomla/joomla.php#L23-L29) is they have set private class variables for `$eid` and `$installer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugin class name must match the plugin name defined in manifest file.

If you have this in the manifest:

```
<filename plugin="installer_log">installer_log.php</filename>
```

Then class name should be `PlgExtensionInstaller_Log`.

Other way around, if class is `PlgExtensionLogInstall`, then manifest should contain this:

```
<filename plugin="loginstall">loginstall.php</filename>
```

Comment: That was it! One of the problems with design by convention is that it can be very hard to figure out which parts are design-critical.